# How can this JavaScript CSV to JSON hook code be optimized to prevent timeouts?

Tags: javascript, json, csv

This code is utilized within a platform that has strict limitations on script execution time,  occasionally being exceeded if there is a very large number of lines within the CSV input that is passed into this script. The script then outputs JSON by capturing the necessary data from each CSV line, and grouping data based upon a few columns. Are there any obvious optimizations that could or should be made here?

```
function prepData (options) {

    // CSV data is passed in on options.data[0]._
    if (options.data[0]) {
        var reportStream = options.data[0]._;
        var reportData = base64Decode(reportStream);

        var testData = "Amount Allocated,Base Segment Code,Code,Code Description (All),Company Code,Company,Employee Name,Employee No.,GL Account No.,GL Account Type Code,GL Account Type,GL Code Type Code,GL Code Type,Hours Allocated,Job Code,Job,Location Code,Location,Org Level 1 Code,Org Level 1,Org 1 Segment,Org Level 2 Code,Org Level 2,Org 2 Segment,Org Level 3 Code,Org Level 3,Org 3 Segment,Org Level 4 Code,Org Level 4,Org 4 Segment,Pay Group Code,Pay Group,Period Control,Period Control Date,Project Code,Project,Suspense Account"
        +"\r\n\"$123.00\",123,12345,Net Cash,ABC,ABC Inc,\"Smith, John\",0001,11-11-11,C,Credit,ND,Net pay,0.0000,ABC,A/P Clerk,ABCINC,ABC HQ,1,Administration,1,123,N/A,123,123,N/A,123,1234,Headquarters,1,1,ABC Inc,20190101,01/01/2019,Z,<None>,N";

        //var preImportData = prepDataForImport(reportData);
        var preImportData = prepDataForImport(testData);
        
        options.data[0].report = [];
        options.data[0].report = preImportData
        options.data[0].report[0].csvData = [];
        options.data[0].report[0].csvData = reportData;
    }
    
    return {
        data: options.data,
        errors: options.errors
    }
    
    function base64Decode(data) {
        var b64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
        var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, i = 0,
        ac = 0,
        dec = "",
        tmp_arr = [];

        if (!data) {
            return data;
        }

        data += '';

        do { // unpack four hexets into three octets using index points in b64
            h1 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
            h2 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
            h3 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
            h4 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));

            bits = h1 << 18 | h2 << 12 | h3 << 6 | h4;

            o1 = bits >> 16 & 0xff;
            o2 = bits >> 8 & 0xff;
            o3 = bits & 0xff;

            if (h3 == 64) {
                tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(o1);
            } else if (h4 == 64) {
                tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(o1, o2);
            } else {
                tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(o1, o2, o3);
            }
        } while (i < data.length);

        dec = tmp_arr.join('');

        return dec;
    }
    
    // Is there any way I can optimize this function to be more efficient?
    function prepDataForImport(data) {    
        var columnNum = 11;
        var allTextLines = data.split(/\r\n|\n/);
        var entries = allTextLines[0].match(/(".*?"|[^",]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g);
        var lines = [];
        
        var locationIndex;
        var glAccountTypeIndex;
        var accountIndex;
        var employeeColumnIndex;
        var payGroupIndex;
        var summaryAmountIndex; 

        var headings = entries.splice(0, columnNum);
      
        for (var i = 0; i < columnNum; i++) {
            if (headings[i].toLowerCase() == 'location') {
              headings[i] = 'LOC';
              locationIndex = i;
            }
            else if (headings[i].toLowerCase() == 'gl account type') {
              headings[i] = 'GAT';
              glAccountTypeIndex = i;
            }
            else if (headings[i].toLowerCase() == 'base segment code') {
              headings[i] = 'BSC';
              accountIndex = i;
            }
            else if (headings[i].toLowerCase().indexOf('employee name') > -1) {
              headings[i] = 'EN';
              employeeColumnIndex = i;
            }
            else if (headings[i].toLowerCase().indexOf('pay group') > -1) {
              headings[i] = 'PG';
              payGroupIndex = i;
            }
            else if (headings[i].toLowerCase().indexOf('ee number') > -1) {
              headings[i] = 'EE';
            }
            else if (headings[i].toLowerCase().indexOf('summary(amount allocated)') > -1) {
              headings[i] = 'SAA';
              summaryAmountIndex = i;
            }
            else if (headings[i].toLowerCase() == 'amount allocated') {
              headings[i] = 'AA';
            }
            else if (headings[i].toLowerCase().indexOf('org 4 segment') > -1) {
              headings[i] = 'O4S';
            }
        }
      
        var employeeObj;
        var employeeName;
        var finalArray = [];
        for (var i = 1; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
            var values = {};
            var creditAmount = 0;
            var debitAmount = 0;
            var skipLine = false;
            employeeObj = {};
            employeeName = '';
        
            var columns = allTextLines[i].match(/(".*?"|[^",]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g);
            
            if (columns) {
                // Pay group + location used to group journal entry lines
                var concatIndexString = columns[locationIndex] + '|' + columns[payGroupIndex];
                var glAccountType = columns[glAccountTypeIndex];
                var accountId = columns[accountIndex];
                employeeName = columns[employeeColumnIndex];
                
                if (accountId == "NOGL" || !accountId) skipLine = true;
                
                for (var j = 0; j < columnNum; j++) {
                    if (headings[j].toLowerCase() === "aa") {
                        columns[j] = columns[j].replace("$", "");
                        columns[j] = columns[j].replace(/,/g, "");
                        columns[j] = columns[j].replace(/\"/g, "");
                        if (glAccountType.toLowerCase() == 'debit') debitAmount = columns[j];
                        else creditAmount = columns[j];
                    }
                    values[headings[j]] = columns[j];
                    delete values['SAA'];
                }
                
                var outerObj = {
                  'outerPayroll': [],
                  'csvData': []
                };

                if (!skipLine) {
                    values['creditAmount'] = creditAmount;
                    values['debitAmount'] = debitAmount;

                    var groupObject = {
                        key: concatIndexString,
                        entries: []
                    };

                    var groupedIndex = lines.map(function(e){ return e.key; }).indexOf(concatIndexString);

                    var employeeIndex = -1;
                    if (groupedIndex == -1) {
                        lines.push(groupObject);
                        groupedIndex = (lines.length - 1);
                        lines[groupedIndex].entries = [];
                    }
                    
                    lines[groupedIndex].entries.push(values)
                } // End of skip line check
            }
          
            // split sub-reports when 750 lines reached
            if (i % 750 == 0 || i == (allTextLines.length-1)) {
                outerObj['outerPayroll'] = lines;
                finalArray.push(outerObj);
                lines = [];
            }
        }
                
        return finalArray;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Hey, Jordan, what if you put a simple example of input and the expected output? I think that's easier to understand what problem you're trying to solve :)